# If Different Higher or Equal Set Text, Based on Excel List Selection

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here's the description of the problem that I want to develop in excel.

If "C1-B1" difference equal or greater than 3 & "D1" list (created in data validation) selected "Pending" set "E1" value as "w". (in here C1 can be empty, if it empty assume it value as today's date)

If "C1-B1" difference equal or greater than 5 & "D1" list (created in data validation) selected "Pending" set "E1" value as "x". (in here C1 can be empty, if it empty assume it value as today's date)

If "C1-B1" difference lower than 3 & "D1" cell list (created in data validation) selected "Pending", set "E1" value as "y".  (in here C1 can be empty, if it empty assume it value as today's date)

If "D1" list (created in data validation) selected, other than "Pending" set "E1" value as "z".

I need to put three difference values to "E1", because I want to use count equation to calculate the "E" Colum total "w" & "x"in this table.

In this scenario, "C" & "B" columns use dates (MM/DD/YYYY) and B column some data can be empty.

In summary, this situation I want to count over 3-4 days (at today date) & over 5 days pending number of items in excel sheet.

Comment: Something like: `=IF(D1="Pending",IF(C1-B1<3,"Y",IF(C1-B1>=5,"X","W")),"Z")`. Would that work? Also, why have you tagged vba?

Comment: Thank you @JvdV for your reply. If there's no value in 'C1' cell it always gives result "Y", even "B1" date is over 5 days (from today). Anyway to correct it?  I though this issue can use VBA that's why I added vba. I want to distinguished between 3-4 days and over 5 days pendings.

Comment: But what is the outcome when B1 is empty? You have not mentioned that scenario, just that B1 can be empty which equals 0, hence the outcome of "Y".

Comment: In my situation B1 always filled. As per your suggested equation if B1 empty, it gives result "Z".

Comment: But what is the problem when it's always filled? Also, per my last comment, what would you want the output to be when B1 is empty. Would that also differ per value of D1

Comment: There's no any issue, if B1 always filled. If C1 empty i want to assume it as todays date. In my situation B1 always filled.

Comment: You'll have to replace the `C1` parts in my suggestion with another `IF` function that checks if the cell is empty, if true, then `TODAY()` else `C1`.

Comment: If the B1 cell doesn't have any value (empty cell) are there any possibility to added no data to E1. Right now it gives Z.